# Skip validation when form timed out

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I need the form to be automatically submitted when timed out,
but seems the form is still checking for the validation even when timed out.
How can I skip the validation and submit the form once time up.
(The validateForm function is checking all the radio button is checked.)

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm()"/>

if(secs == 0 )
{
    document.forms["test_form"].submit();
}
```

Comment: Paste your entire code here

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! In order for us to help you better, can you please update your question so that it shows your **relevant code** in a [**minimal, complete, and verifiable example**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve); we can't resolve your problem without seeing it! ;) It would also be helpful if you could let us know what you have tried so far to solve your problem. For further information, please refer to the help article regarding [**how to ask good questions**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [**tour of the site**](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: I hope you know what you're doing (i.e. treating that data very carefully if you're going to skip validation... never trust the user)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One simple way can be having two submit buttons.

One with the validation:

```
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" onclick="return validateForm()"/>
```

Other without validation with display none property:

```
<input type="submit" id="force_submit" style="display:none;" name="timeout_submit" value="Submit"/>
```

Then on timeout click the `force_submit` button:

```
if(secs == 0 )
{
    document.getElementById('force_submit').click();
}
```

Comment: Wouldn't that allow a user to just inspect, change the style on the force_submit item and then inject malicious code?

Comment: Well! You wanted to submit the form anyway (validated or not) after time up. I think you know what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: Hey, I didn't :D - I'm not sure what he's trying to accomplish :P

Comment: Sorry! I couldn't notice that you are not the question asker.

Comment: For future reference, the question asker has a highlight on the name when commenting. :)